# REST API - File Upload using HTTP Request with multiple parameter in apex (salesforce)

Tags: apex, rest-api, integration, httprequest

I'm trying to post form data using HTTP request with multipart/form-data with multiple parameters but It's always showing error "invalid file contents".

**{"http_code":400,"total_time":"0.01579427719116211","status":"Failed","message":"invalid file contents","input_file_name":"AUTOP_BOATP_HOMEP_PROPP_1_masked.al3","output_format":"json","transaction_id":"17c3b122-f10d-4dd6-a297-71fcfe7da295","output":"{}","total_policies":0}**

Please check my code below.

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
     public static String getDataUriFromUri(String url) {
          HttpRequest req1 = new HttpRequest();
          req1.setEndpoint(url);
          req1.setMethod('GET');
          Http binding = new Http();
          HttpResponse res1 = binding.send(req1);
          //get Blob data from al3 file URL.
          Blob image = res1.getBodyAsBlob();
          String FileData = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(image);
                  
          HttpRequest req2 = new HttpRequest();
          req2.setEndpoint('https://apis.winsurtech.com/al3/v2/conversion');
          req2.setMethod('POST'); 
          req2.setCompressed(true);
          req2.setHeader('content-type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW');
          req2.setHeader('Content-Length',String.valueof(FileData.length()));
          req2.setHeader('user-secret', 'XXXX');
                    
          req2.setbody('------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="input_file"; filename="AUTOP_BOATP_HOMEP_PROPP_1_masked.al3"\r\n\r\n'+FileData+'\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="output_format"\r\n\r\nJSON\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--');
                    
          Http http = new Http();
          HttpResponse res2 = http.send(req2);
          System.debug('Data::'+res2.getBody());
          return FileData;

      }
```

Comment: You have just disclosed your user secret to the Internet by pasting it here. Bots regularly crawl Stack Exchange looking for credentials to exploit. You should revoke and replace this credential **immediately**.